# How do I make it call the right constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

When I create an array of a user-defined class like this, it will default-construct each element:

```
S s[5]; // calls default constructor five times, one for each S object
```

But what if my class is not default-construable? How will I be able to instantiate and later use this array?

For example, my class `S` may not be default-construable, but it *does* have another constructor like this:

```
S(int, int);
```

How do I make it call this constructor instead of the default one?

Comment: Use a container instead of an array.

Comment: Use a container _and_ construct from iterators, or an `emplace_back` loop, or simply construct them one at a time.

Comment: Or give the class a default constructor, unless you have a *really good reason* not to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct S
{
   const int m;
   S(int p, int k) : m(p) {}
};

S arr[4] = {S(1,1), S(1,2), S(1,3), S(1,4)};
```

Without copy-ctor, you could still use the following C++11 list-initialization -- as [Andy Prowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932150/andy-prowl) points out the ctor may not be `explicit` for this:

```
S arr[4] = {{1,1}, {1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}};
```

---

For a more scalable solution, you can use either `std::array` or `std::vector`:

```
std::array<S,4> make_array()
{
    // create array... and return
}

std::array<S,4> arr = make_array();
```

Comment: Please leave a comment if you downvote. I just checked this compiles btw.

Comment: Actually, I re-thought my downvote.  OP requested doing this without a default constructor, so that doesn't leave many options.  Downvote removed.

Comment: Thank you, you and Andy's answer helped a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use an `std::vector` and fill it up with objects that *you* decide how should be constructed.

For instance, in C++11 you could use the `emplace_back()` member function to write something like this:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<S> v;
v.emplace_back(42, 1729);
v.emplace_back(0, 6);
// ...
```

Or even:

```
std::vector<S> v = { {42, 1729}, {0, 6} };
```

If the constructor of `S` is not marked as `explicit`. If that is the case, you would have to write:

```
std::vector<S> v = { S{42, 1729}, S{0, 6} }.
```

Back in C++03, where `emplace_back()` and uniform initialization did not exist, you could have done:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<S> v;
v.push_back(S(42, 1729));
v.push_back(S(0, 6));
// ...
```

But your class should be copyable in order for that to compile.

Answer (score 2):

in the past i did some:

```
S** s = new S*[5];

s[0] = new S(1, 2);
s[1] = new S(1, 2);
```

just to be able to call the other constructors

Comment: @Joel No it won't, because were using pointers instead of the actual objects. The array will instantiate the pointers, and we assign a correctly-construed object to them.

Comment: @user2030677 sorry, i was far from a compiler and couldn't try :) fixed